# How to update files from SVN to Jenkins workspace?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am using selenium webdriver 2.47.1 and TestNG for automation process. I am using Jenkins for continuous integration purpose. All my automation scripts are stored in Linux server where Jenkins is installed. I have already created one Jenkins job(Free-Style) with Advanced Project Options as Use Custom Workspace & Source Code Management selected as None. The Job is working perfectly.

I want to update files from SVN through Jenkins. If Build Now button is clicked for particular job: means latest files from SVN should be committed & than Build should start. How can I achieve this..? I am searching for the solution since yesterday.

Subversion Plugin configuration shown in image.. I am using Jenkins 1.627 & Subversion Plugin 2.5.3
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify "commit files from SVN through Jenkins"? Is the Jenkins job creating new files or modifying existing files, which you need to check back into SVN?

Comment: In my project there are several test engineers. Both of them have access to Jenkins as well as SVN. For Example TE1 created automation script and stored it in SVN, He created Jenkins job to the script. After TE2 modifies the automation script prepared by TE1. Now the SVN files got updated. When we are trying to build Jenkins job the latest updated file should be taken for execution which is modified by TE2 7 not the old one prepared by TE1.

Comment: The correct term is **update**, not *commit*. You said: "Source Code Management selected as None". What happens if you select SVN?

Comment: I have tried [Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) for SVN Configuration. Configuration details are displayed in edited question as image. If I am clicking on Build Now button it should clean the local directory & update it with new file and than run the script. But I am getting error as shown below `Building in workspace /home/probe7qa/probe7qa.svn/icoreemrtests/onc2014/170.314.a.9/src/eNotes
Cleaning local Directory src
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/../../src/eNotes/ExcelLibrary.java`

Comment: I noticed you are using custom workspace. "AccessDeniedException" seems like a pretty obvious problem to me: Jenkins does not have write access there.

Comment: Do you think that changing workspace to the Jenkins installed directory may solve this issue..?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I have stored all my automation script in the directory where Jenkins installed.. It actually running the script without any problem.. Jenkins is installed in /var/lib/ directory. Is this safe to save all my scripts in to that location. Even-though as a user I don't have permission to commit the files particular location..

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, your problem is that Jenkins is being used to validate the test bed itself. The QA project I am currently assigned to is set up this way, which I don't think is right. IMO, your test bed should be stable enough to test your actual software and if changes to the test bed occur, you should simply update the Jenkins workspace without making it test itself.